# Force URL to be http and not https

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, web-config

I'm running a WordPress / WooCommerce site. Most URLs have no problem with being SSL / https, now with one plug-in I found it causes a problem on HTTPS so I want the URL for this plugin to be HTTP instead of HTTPS.

The URL looks like this:

`https://www.example.com/ontwerp-zelf/?product_id=1432&cart_id=d866d4bd644dd570146434238434f345`

I want to rewrite it so that when it finds `ontwerp-zelf` in the string it automatically rewrites to HTTP.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from HTTPS back to HTTP for URLs that contain the string "ontwerp-zelf" (at the start), try the following (before your existing WP directives but *after* your existing canonical redirects):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(ontwerp-zelf.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note that the order of directives in `.htaccess` is important.

This is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Change this to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.

However, you need to also *exclude* these URLs from being redirected in your existing canonical HTTP to HTTPS redirect, as otherwise you will end up with a redirect loop. So, if you currently have something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then you will need to insert an additional condition to prevent it from being redirected to HTTPS in the first place.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ontwerp-zelf
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The *CondPattern* `!^/ontwerp-zelf` states that the `REQUEST_URI` must not start with `/ontwerp-zelf`.